# Is it possible to create an external content type from WCF service with message security?

Tags: security, external-content-type, wcf, bdc-model

I have an external content type that consumes a WCF service. So far it's something simple, over HTTP, no security, just for tests. [Here is a sample to get an idea](http://malikhan.wordpress.com/2010/01/11/business-connectivity-services-bcs-using-wcf-sharepoint-designer-2010/).

Now I'm stepping up a gear and want to connect the external content type to a service that uses message level security. The SOAP is on HTTP but the body and headers are encrypted and signed.

Is it possible to use message security to connect to the service from SharePoint or only transport security is a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I could figure out: NO :(

But, you can create an external content type from a .NET Type connection (`Type="DotNetAssembly"`) and write your client programmatically in there and your stereotyped operations from the assembly will delegate to the WCF service.